# a function from the drupal book module

Tags: php, drupal, function

```
              <?php
function template_preprocess_book_navigation(&$variables) {
  $book_link = $variables['book_link'];

 // Provide extra variables for themers. Not needed by default.
$variables['book_id'] = $book_link['bid'];
$variables['book_title'] = check_plain($book_link['link_title']);
$variables['book_url'] = 'node/' . $book_link['bid'];
$variables['current_depth'] = $book_link['depth'];

 $variables['tree'] = '';
 if ($book_link['mlid']) {
 $variables['tree'] = book_children($book_link);
}
```

i can't understand it well, anyone can explain it for me. thank you, what's the aim of this line "$book_link = $variables['book_link'];" how should i know $book_link is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I understand it: The argument `$variables` is an array passed into the function by reference.  One of it's elements is `$variables['book_link']`, which has some additional information about the book.

That block of 4 lines is basically copying values from the `$variables['book_link']` array and moving them up one level:

- `$variables['book_link']['bid']` -> `$variables['book_id']`
- `$variables['book_link']['link_title']` -> `$variables['book_title']`

etc.

Then the last block of code determines if there are any child items to show in the navigation. If so, place them into `$variables['tree']`.

Comment: $book_link = $variables['book_link']; form this line, that the $book_link only have one value, why in the following, that have $book_link['bid'];...etc

Comment: @enjoylife: Because `$variables['book_link']` is not just a single value, its actually an array. The line `$book_link = $variables['book_link'];` is copying that array into a new one called `$book_link`.

Comment: @enjoylife: the preprocess function only takes one variable (named `$variables`), so any additional information needs to be passed in like that. Since the function is manipulating several values, the author decided to pass in those values as an array-within-an-array and extract them later. Does that make sense?

Comment: $variables['book_link'] is not just a single value, its actually an array. i know it's an array,but form the php manual. $variables['book_link'] is an Associative array. like this $salaries["Bob"] = 2000; $salaries["Bob"] has only one value. why$variables['book_link'] can have a lots of values? thank you,

Comment: You can have arrays nested inside arrays. `$variables['book_link']` was probably built using code like this: `$variables['book_link'] = array('bid' => 123, 'link_title' => 'Some Book Title');` In the example you gave, you assigned a number to `$salaries['Bob']` - what if you assigned an associative array to `$salaries['Bob']` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The function sets up the variables that are available in [book-navigation.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--book--book-navigation.tpl.php/7). The function is called (along with other preprocess functions) in response to a call of

```
theme('book-navigation', $variables);
```

See *[Setting up variables for use in a template](http://drupal.org/node/223430)* for how this works.

My guess is, `$variables['book_link']` is an array when the [`theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme) function is called. But to be sure, you will have to search the sources of Drupal.